# What is iBridge

Tags: macbook-pro

I got the 15 inch 2016 MacBook Pro. Today I went to the System Profiler, and the USB section, there are an item called iBridge. Here are a screenshot (I covered up the serial number just in case):

[image]

Just for the curiosity, what is that?

P.S. I am running Sierra 10.12.1 (12B2659)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The iBridge is the USB link to the Touch Bar. It is noted in http://arstechnica.com/video/2016/11/the-2016-13-and-15-inch-touch-bar-macbook-pros-reviewed/ in the "Inner workings..." section.

Answer (score 5):

iBridge is the code name for the [T series coprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple-designed_processors#T_series) (e.g. T1 or [T2 chip](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208862)) in newer Macs. It manages the Touch ID sensor, as well as the FaceTime camera and audio control. It is present even on Macs that don't have a Touch Bar, like the 2018 MacBook Air and Mac mini.